# CSS not working in prod. Vue.js, Tailwind & Netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, netlify

I am extremely puzzled...this is my 2nd vue.js project. It's giving me massive issues when I push the site live.

The app works locally without any issue, but after pushing to netlify and building the CSS doesnt seem to work. I am using purgecss this is my `postcss.config.js` file:

```
const IN_PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss')('tailwind.js'),
        require('autoprefixer')(),
        IN_PRODUCTION &&
            require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
                content: ['./public/**/*.html', './src/**/*.vue'],
                defaultExtractor(content) {
                    const contentWithoutStyleBlocks = content.replace(
                        /<style[^]+?<\/style>/gi,
                        ''
                    );
                    return (
                        contentWithoutStyleBlocks.match(
                            /[A-Za-z0-9-_/:]*[A-Za-z0-9-_/]+/g
                        ) || []
                    );
                },
                whitelist: [],
                whitelistPatterns: [
                    /-(leave|enter|appear)(|-(to|from|active))$/,
                    /^(?!(|.*?:)cursor-move).+-move$/,
                    /^router-link(|-exact)-active$/,
                    /data-v-.*/,
                ],
            }),
    ],
};
```

As per the TW and PurgeCSS instructions. This again works locally...but not in prod.

Netlify build command is `npm run build` and it's served from the `dist` folder.

You can see the app here: https://beautify-urls.netlify.app/
And repo here: https://github.com/mrpbennett/beautify-url

I am not using `scoped` on my style tags

any ideas would be much appericated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the **Publish directory** field from `dist` to `/dist`.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I havent done this before. Also the netlify instructions state I should just use dist

Comment: It would be really great if you can please have a look at this question and provide some work-around? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72198087/7584240 Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In the instructions here -> https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/11/30/how-to-deploy-a-vue-site/

Comment: In the instructions here -> https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/11/30/how-to-deploy-a-vue-site/

we have "use the build command npm run build or yarn build. Set the publish directory to dist."

I've tried dist /dist and dist/ to no hope.